# submit button is not working for validating form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a code when I click on the submit button The text will appear just for less than 1 second how can I make it forever?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#" method="post" onSubmit="return validcheck()">
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
    <input type="submit">
    <div id="error1"></div>
  </form>

  <script>
    function validcheck() {
      var checkingg = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
      if (checkingg == null || checkingg == "") {
        document.getElementById('error1').innerHTML = 'please write something here';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('name-error').innerHTML = '';
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code to inhibit form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return false from your method:

```
    function validcheck() {
      var checkingg = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
      if (checkingg == null || checkingg == "") {
        document.getElementById('error1').innerHTML = 'please write something here';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('name-error').innerHTML = '';
      }
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: it is worked but the question is what if we write the return false; in the else{} or if{} and the other question is what does exactly return false; do?

Comment: Returning false basically prevents any further events from bubbling, so in this case it prevents the form from being submitted. For that reason, you only need to return false when the data is invalid

Answer (score 0):

You are missing return statement

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#" method="post" onSubmit="return validcheck()">
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
    <input type="submit">
    <div id="error1"></div>
  </form>

  <script>
    function validcheck() {
      var checkingg = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
      if (checkingg == null || checkingg == "") {
        document.getElementById('error1').innerHTML = 'please write something here';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('name-error').innerHTML = '';
      }
 return false;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give action as below.

```
 <form action="javascript:void(0)" method="post" onSubmit="return validcheck()">
```